# how to lock process in tomcat?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, web

I have a web application running on tomcat. I have a jersey2 application there. So when an incoming request comes, I need to lock the process associated with this request until getting response from an external service. How to do that without getting the system working slower or even crash?

Comment: Spawn a thread with a listener and let that wait. That does not take any significant resources.

Comment: Define 'lock'. And Tomcat is the process, and it isn't associated with just this request. Unclear what you're asking.